# Dockerfile RUN call powershell on Ubuntu-based image

Tags: powershell, docker, dockerfile

I have the following in my Dockerfile:

```
# setup powershell
# Download the Microsoft repository GPG keys
RUN wget -q https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb
# Register the Microsoft repository GPG keys
RUN dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb
# Update the list of products
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libunwind8 \
    libicu55 \
    powershell
# Register Powershell repo
RUN powershell Register-PSRepository ...
```

According to everything I have read, this should work, however I get the following output during `docker build` (censored with sensitive info).

```
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu11) ...
Setting up liburcu4:amd64 (0.9.1-3) ...
Setting up liblttng-ust-ctl2:amd64 (2.7.1-1) ...
Setting up liblttng-ust0:amd64 (2.7.1-1) ...
Setting up powershell (7.0.0-1.ubuntu.16.04) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu11) ...
Removing intermediate container 1ef0413ecd13
 ---> a5323d6c8301
Step 12/23 : RUN powershell Register-PSRepository     ...<snip>...
 ---> Running in 604784872cc8
/bin/sh: 1: powershell: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c powershell Register-PSRepository ...<snip>... returned a non-zero code: 127
```

I am at a loss as to why powershell is not found bearing in mind that `apt-get install` call for it was successful.

How do invoke `powershell` after successfully installing it using `apt-get`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you install powershell, you should be able to call it using

> pwsh

Answer (score 1):

As discovered from this blog, the executable changed name from 5.1 to 6.0 (aka Powershell Core): https://www.starwindsoftware.com/blog/using-powershell-on-linux

- For Powershell v1.0 - 5.1 - `powershell.exe` on Windows
- For Powershell v6.0+ - `pwsh.exe` on Windows, invoked as `pwsh` on MacOS and Linux

So the correct call is:

```
RUN pwsh -Command Register-PSRepository ... <etc>
```